# Generate thumbnails from uploaded videos via file input in React

Tags: reactjs, video, file-upload, thumbnails

I have a video uploading part in my React app where a user uploads multiple videos(.mp4) and the thumbnails of selected videos are displayed before they are sent to the server. Through searching, I could find https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/, but it is for generating thumbnails for uploaded images.

How can I generate thumbnails of uploaded videos in React? Anh help is highly appreciated.